# Give Non Root group of Users access to start mysqld service

Tags: sudo, root, service

I have a Non Root User `abc`,`abc2`.....

I want to add this to a group of users and want to give the group of user s`sudo` rights only to `restart`, `start` or `stop` - `mysqld service`. i.e `sudo service mysqld restart`. How can I do it so?